# Not able to get hyperlink in Email Template MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I am using below synatx in email template in MVC but could not see url part only see static content "Click on this link to Approve/Reject Request"

When i do right click on view source i am able to see my url "http://localhost/ABC"

```
<h3><font color="navy">Click on this link to Approve/Reject Request : <a href="@Model.ApprovalLink"></a></font></h3>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you expecting to see the value of the `href` attribute? If you want to display it, then you could use `<a href="@Model.ApprovalLink">@Model.ApprovalLink</a>`, but why not add the text "Click on this link to Approve/Reject Request" between the `<a>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `@Model.ApprovalLink` URL text inside the `<a>` tag as well:

```
<h3><font color="navy">Click on this link to Approve/Reject Request : <a href="@Model.ApprovalLink">@Model.ApprovalLink</a></font></h3>
```